# jQuery Random reward point system

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am quite new to jQuery. 
I am making a game in HTML 5, jQuery and CSS.

I want to create a random point system for an object. This is what I have now, but the random point system doesn't work 100%. When the color is: colors[1] then the variable (reward points) needs to be 5. If it is colors[2], it needs to be 10 as example. Here is the code:

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/39r1xfhc/1/

// Point Object
var Point;
var pointID = 0;
var speed = 3;
var rewardPoints;
var colors;
var rand;

function Points() {
this.drawY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 260);

pointID++;

// Colors for Points
colors = ["#0F0","#F00C00","#00E1FF"];                
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);           

if(colors[rand] === colors[1]) {
    rewardPoints = 5;

    Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
    $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY, 'background-color': colors[1]});

    canvasPoints.append(Point); // Spawn Point
} else if(colors[rand] === colors[2]) {
    rewardPoints = 10;

    Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
    $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY, 'background-color': colors[2]});

    canvasPoints.append(Point); // Spawn Point
} else if(colors[rand] === colors[3]) {
    rewardPoints = 20;

    Point = $('<div id="' + pointID + '" class="point"></div>');
    $(Point).css({'right': '0', 'top': this.drawY, 'background-color': colors[3]});

    canvasPoints.append(Point); // Spawn Point
}
}
```

Comment: what is `canvasPoints` ? How should we help? Can you show an example?

Comment: You should say you're quite new to `Javascript`.

Comment: Could you please add working prototype on http://jsfiddle.net/ , it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Yes I am quite new to Javascript. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/39r1xfhc/

Comment: On-topic please. Can someone help me?